# does white noise without mean zero do some changes?

Tags: matlab, stochastic-process

again my question is related to  white noise ,but with different  meaning.let us compare following two  code.first

```
function [ x ] = generate(N,m,A3)
f1 = 100;
f2 = 200;
T = 1./f1;
t = (0:(N*T/m):(N*T))'; %'
wn = rand(length(t),1).*2 - 1;
x = 20.*sin(2.*pi.*f1.*t) + 30.*cos(2.*pi.*f2.*t) + A3.*wn;
%[pks,locs] = findpeaks(x);
 plot(x)
end
```

using `generate(3,500,10)`

graph of this code is following

[image]

but let us change our code so that it makes  zero mean with white noise

```
function [ x ] = generate1(N,m,A3)
f1 = 100;
f2 = 200;
T = 1./f1;
t = (0:(N*T/m):(N*T))'; %'
wn = rand(length(t),1).*2 - 1;
mn=wn-mean(wn);
x = 20.*sin(2.*pi.*f1.*t) + 30.*cos(2.*pi.*f2.*t) + A3.*mn;
%[pks,locs] = findpeaks(x);
 plot(x)
end
```

and graph is following
[image]

if we compare these two picture,we  could say that it is  almost  same,just some  changes,so does matter  if we make zero mean or not?for real analysis,like for finding 
peaks and  so on.thanks very much

UPDATED:
there is updated code

```
function [ x ] = generate1(N,m,A3)
f1 = 100;
f2 = 200;
T = 1./f1;
t = (0:(N*T/m):(N*T))'; %'
wn = randn(length(t),1); %zero mean variance 1
x = 20.*sin(2.*pi.*f1.*t) + 30.*cos(2.*pi.*f2.*t) + A3.*wn;
%[pks,locs] = findpeaks(x);
 plot(x)
end
```

[image]

and it's picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial noise is uniformly distributed between  -1 & +1

Your second noise is also uniformly disributed between -1 & +1, because mean is already zero, subtracting it is meaningless

in order to obtain white noise you can use `randn()` function:

```
wn = randn(length(t),1); %zero mean variance 1
```

You may not observe any much difference again if your noise  coefficient A3 has a  much lower value compared to 20 & 30 which are the coefficients of your signal.

In order to find peaks, adding noise may not serve any purpose because noise tends to decrease the information content of signals

Comment: so what would  be effective code for white noise?could you edit your answer  related to my  white noise code?

Comment: i will change it,and i will upload again picture

Comment: The OP is subtracting the *sample* mean, which has an expected value of 0, but will not actually be 0. This actually has the effect of reducing the variance...

Comment: i have updated,right  Amplitude is small,but for large  value  what is a chance that it may have some effect?

Comment: i have posted my effort what i have done and asked question,is it worth to downvote?

Comment: In order to find peaks, adding noise may not serve any purpose because noise tends to decrease the information content of signals

Comment: i am sure,because it is not   funy question,so please it is better some guys  not to  disturb others,yes for peaks  it is not  question with this.just for  white noise

Comment: @dato: I downvoted because you don't appear to have given this much thought. The mean is a scalar value, i.e. a constant. What effect does adding a constant have on the resulting graph?

Comment: ok thanks for your help  @fatih_k  i will accept it,i think  there is nothing to add  right to my question,about amplitude it is just experiment deal

Comment: now imagine that i did not know it,instead do some like this,just tell me

Answer (score 1):

What is the value of mean(wm)?  If it is close to zero, then no, it does not matter.

Technically, white noise has zero mean by [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_noise#White_noise_vector).